# SQL : how to distinguish between different rows with same value in some field and have a separate function applied to another field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query output showing a list of orders. Some orders might occupy more then one record in the query output if those orders consist of sub-orders.Each sub-order occupies a separate line in the output. There is the OrderID column which has the same value for all sub-orders in the output:

```
OrderID    Sub-Order  Price
1             1         100
1             2         50
2             1         30
3             1         50
```

I need to add a column  "Discount" to the output and fill it by following rules:

1. If certain order has one sub-order - the discount is 10% of the Price
2. If certain order has more than one sub-order, the discount is 20% on all sub-orders'

My query is a UNION of two SELECTs.

I use mssql with ms sql studio

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the edit. What markup did you use please ?

Comment: When you click on the help icon (the question mark) in the upper right corner when editing your question you are taken here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting which explains all that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE` and `COUNT` window function

```
SELECT OrderID, Sub-Order, Price,
     CASE WHEN (count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderID)) > 1 
          THEN Price * 0.8
          ELSE Price * 0.9
     END
FROM ( table or <query> )
```

Comment: sounds promising, will try. Can this be applied if my query is union of two queries ?

Comment: @LouisShraga you probably mean whether you can use this approach if `table` is a union of two queries. Definitely yes, you just replace `table` by `(<your union query here>) table`.